# LoL: Is there a difference between Ranked Summoner names and Normal summoner names?

Tags: league-of-legends

This is a really simple question but I was not able to find the answer to it. But is the name used in Ranked teams different from the Summoner name you use normally? I've seen team names in the Summoner name, but do people just change their names to that?

For example, my Summoner name is VirusThePanda, and my (Future) Ranked team is HCG. So would my name in Ranked become HCG VirusThePanda or do I need to actually change my Summoner name to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Prior to the removal of 5v5 Team Ranked, you were able to make a ranked team that, while playing with your team in the Team Ranked queue, your team's tag would be prepended to your Summoner name.</strike>

If you're playing on a ranked team, in Ranked Team 5v5, your team's tag is prepended to your Summoner name.

Typically, when people want to represent their affiliation all the time, they just buy a name change (you can buy with IP) and add the team affiliation to their name.

Clubs will bring back affiliation prepending and allow it to be toggle-able. I'm not certain of the ETA on the clubs feature though.

Comment: So because Ranked 5v5 was removed, I cannot have the Tag prepended? What about if it was in Ranked 3v3?

Comment: @VirusThePanda Specifically *Team* Ranked 5v5, yes. Ranked 3v3 doesn't have teams IIRC.

Comment: @VirusThePanda Although, clubs are coming soon which may allow affiliation prepending. There's not enough information to make that assumption though.

Comment: Ranked 3v3 certainly did have teams (unsure if it still does or not), and yes you'd get your tag for that. There was no ranked 3v3 that wasnt teams

Comment: @BenCraig Thanks for the clarification, ranked 3v3 is not something I'm very familiar with.

Comment: np - 3v3 (solo and ranked teams) was the only game mode I played for about 2 years

Comment: @nukeforum That sort of functionality is currently on the PBE. You can add tags to your club and it will show up in-game. It's covered here on [surrender@20](http://www.surrenderat20.net/p/current-pbe-balance-changes.html#unreleased)

Comment: @VanBuzzKill That's what I get for not having played on the PBE for 9 months! Boy does that look rad though!

Comment: Ranked Team 5V5 isn't permanently disabled. Don't misguide people

Comment: @Oak I basically write all my answers from memory. It isn't my intent to misguide, I was under the impression that dynamic queue was replacing everything.